# How to submit a php select inside form using jquery

Tags: php, jquery, forms

I have a form which only has one selector in it whos options are mostly populated by php which currently get submitted by `<input type="submit" name="courseSubmit"/>`

```
echo '<form name="CourseForm" action="" method="post">';
echo '<select name="CourseSelect"><option value="0">Select Course</option>';
$result = mysqli_query($con,"  SELECT * FROM course c ");
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
            {


echo "<option value='".$row['IDNum']."' ".$select.">" . $row['Title'] . "</option>";                

            }

echo '</select>';
echo '<input name="CourseSubmit" type="submit"/></form>';
```

Upon clicking the button the page is submitted then by using `$_POST['CourseSelect']` i can get the value of the select.

However when I try replacing the functionality of the submit button with `onchange="this.form.submit()"` inside of my select the form does not appear to be submitted

I know I can call js functions from php for example

`echo "<select onchange="myjsFunction()">";`

there a way using jquery to submit the form in the exact same manor as using `<input type="submit"/>` ?

Comment: "form" in not a property of "this", which is the button itself. The form is a parent, not a child of the button.

Comment: The `form` property of an input element is the form that contains it.

Comment: Are you getting a Javascript error when `this.form.submit()` executes?

Comment: I do not appear to be getting a js error the page seems to submit but nothing happens.

Comment: It works fine here: http://jsfiddle.net/barmar/3ezZ8/2/

Comment: Does your PHP script check `if (isset($_POST['CourseSubmit']))`? The submit button won't be set if you didn't use it to submit the form.

Answer (score 0):

You *could* do something like:

```
$('select[name=CourseSelect]').change(function(){
     $(this).closest('form').submit();
});
```

And ignore the onchange attribute entirely for the HTML element.

Here's a recursive example:
http://jsfiddle.net/erXxd/1/

Comment: Would this work with multiple forms on the same page?

Comment: Yes. You could just use $('select') as the selector, it will submit whatever the parent form is (closest searches through ancestors for an element that matches the selector).

edit: or maybe not... gotta put an example together I guess before making a bold claim.

Comment: Alright. Bold claim proven:
http://jsfiddle.net/erXxd/3/
(please keep in mind it appears Chrome won't even try to load Google in an iFrame, so the second dropdown may appear to be broken --- I created this in IE)